# Expected value of couples: recurrence relation?

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

$n$ couples are formed randomly from an initial group of $n$ men and $n$ women.

Denote men from $1$ to $n$ and let $X_i=1$ if the $i$-th man is associated to a women and $0$ otherwise. Let $X=\sum_{I=1}^{100}X_i$.
**The purpose of the exercise is to compute the expected value of each $X_i$ and then of $X$**

We have that each $X_i$ is a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $$P(X_i=1)$$ but I feel that $P(X_i=1)$ depends on $i.$ I mean for $i=1$ we have $P(X_1=1)=\frac{n}{2n-1}$ but $P(X_2=1)$ will depend on the previous probability and I want to use $$P(X_2=1)=P(X_2=1\vert X_1=1)P(X_1=1)+P(X_2=1\vert X_1=0)P(X_1=0).$$

> Is there a recurrence relation or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working out the equality in your question we find:$$P(X_2=1)=\frac{n-1}{2n-2}\frac{n}{2n-1}+\frac{n}{2n-2}\frac{n-1}{2n-1}=\frac{n}{2n-1}=P(X_1=1)$$This *confirms* (but does not prove) that $P(X_i=1)$ does not depend on $i$ but I can imagine that this on its own does not yet satisfy you.

In your thinking try to discard the order of associating in the following way:

There are $n$ men and each of them is labeled with a number and is associated with one of the other persons in the group.

Here *resist* the temptation to think of a timescale where the men are associated one by one.

Can you think of *any reason at all* why the man with label $13$ has more (or less) chance to be associated with a woman than the man with label $64$?....

---

edit:

valid proof of: $$P(X_i=1)=\frac{n}{2n-1}\text{ for arbitrary }i\in\{1,\dots,100\}$$

Concerning the association with man $i$ we discern $2n-1$ **equiprobable** candidates and exactly $n$ of them are women. So the probability that he will be associated with a woman equals $\frac{n}{2n-1}$.

Comment: hum that stange how the intuition works here. Without timescale thinking it is obvious that each probability is the same... Thanks a lot

Comment: about your edit: why is does not prove the i.d. property ?

Comment: Because I only proved that $P(X_2=1)=P(X_1=1)$ and not $P(X_i=1)=P(X_1=1)$ for every $i$.

Comment: ah ok, but my induction is true.

Comment: Do we suppose as well that $(X_i)$ are independent?

Comment: No, we do not. And that is not necessary since for linearity of expectation we do not need independence.

Comment: yes, but if we want to compute $E(X_i X_j)$ for $i\ne j$ so we need to compute $P((X_i,X_j)=(1,1))$, is it possible without independence ?

Comment: Sure:$$P\left(X_{1}=1,X_{2}=1\right)=P\left(X_{2}=1\mid X_{1}=1\right)P\left(X_{1}=1\right)=\frac{n-1}{2n-2}\frac{n}{2n-1}$$

Comment: oh right, so finally we have $E(X_i X_j)=P((X_i,X_j)=(1,1))=\frac{n-1}{2n-2}\frac{n}{2n-1}$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: thanks a lot!$\{\}$